# Why is proxy in package.json react causing "Invalid Host header"?

Tags: reactjs, proxy, localhost

I am creating a MERN stack application and I put `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` in React's `package.json` to have a gateway to the server, but on the web page "*Invalid Host header*" gets rendered.

I tried removing the proxy. Is there another way to fix this?